# WINSOCK Socket operation on non-socket

Tags: asynchronous, winsock

Here is the Class Method (all methods and vars are declared public)
NOTE:  DiscoverWinsockLib does the WSAStartup stuff and I know that part works.  It also does a LoadLibrary and finds the DLLs entry points for the functions below, renamed with lpfn_ prefix.

No matter what I do, I can't seem to resolve why I get the error condition of socket operation on non-socket in the Thread.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
bool __fastcall TRANSPORT::Establish (const char *host, int port, int timeout)
{
bool rFlag;
int rval;

rFlag = false;
DiscoverWinsockLib();

if( WSH )
{
    hostEntry = gethostbyname(host);

    if( !hostEntry )
    {
        LastErrorCode = lpfn_WSAGetLastError();
        lpfn_WSACleanup();
        SetErrorMsg();
    }
    else
    {
        CSocket = lpfn_socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

        if (CSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            LastErrorCode = lpfn_WSAGetLastError();
            SetErrorMsg();
            lpfn_WSACleanup();
        }
        else
        {

            RxDataBuf.len = RXDATA_BUFSIZE;
            RxDataBuf.buf = RxBuffer;
            RxOverlapped.hEvent = lpfn_WSACreateEvent();

            if(RxOverlapped.hEvent == WSA_INVALID_EVENT)
            {
                LastErrorCode = lpfn_WSAGetLastError();
                SetErrorMsg();
                SocketShutdown();
                //lpfn_closesocket(CSocket);
            }
            else
            {
                if(lpfn_WSAEventSelect(CSocket, RxOverlapped.hEvent, FD_ALL_EVENTS) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    LastErrorCode = lpfn_WSAGetLastError();
                    SetErrorMsg();
                    lpfn_closesocket(CSocket);
                    lpfn_WSACloseEvent(RxOverlapped.hEvent);
                }
                else
                {
                    hThreadIO = CreateThread(0, 0, ProcessEvents, (void *)this, 0, &ThreadID);

                    // Try to connect to the server
                    serverInfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
                    serverInfo.sin_addr = *((LPIN_ADDR)*hostEntry->h_addr_list);
                    serverInfo.sin_port = htons(port);

                    if( lpfn_connect(CSocket, (LPSOCKADDR)&serverInfo, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR  )
                    {
                        LastErrorCode = lpfn_WSAGetLastError();
                        if( LastErrorCode != WSAEWOULDBLOCK )
                        {
                            SetErrorMsg();
                            SocketShutdown();
                        }
                        else
            rFlag = true;
                    }
                    else
                        rFlag = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return(rFlag);
}
```

And here is the Thread referenced above:

```
DWORD WINAPI ProcessEvents(void *pParam)
{

TRANSPORT *T;
WSANETWORKEVENTS NetEvents;
DWORD EIndex;
DWORD  rc;
bool Failure;


T = (TRANSPORT *)pParam;
Failure = false;

do
{
    EIndex = T->lpfn_WSAWaitForMultipleEvents( 1, &T->RxOverlapped.hEvent, false, 3000, true );

    if( EIndex == WSA_WAIT_FAILED )
    {
        T->LastErrorCode = T->lpfn_WSAGetLastError();
        T->SetErrorMsg();
        Failure = true;
    }

    if( EIndex == WSA_WAIT_TIMEOUT )
    {
        if( T->OnConnectTimeout )
            T->OnConnectTimeout(T);

        Failure = true;
    }

}while( EIndex != WAIT_IO_COMPLETION && !Failure );

if( Failure )
    return(EIndex);

// Get the event(s) that occurred and their associated error array
if(T->lpfn_WSAEnumNetworkEvents(T->CSocket, T->RxOverlapped.hEvent, &NetEvents) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    T->LastErrorCode = T->lpfn_WSAGetLastError();
    T->SetErrorMsg();
    return(EIndex);
}

// =================================================================
// Code above fetches the event that woke this thread up
// Code below deals with the events as they are detected
// =================================================================

if( NetEvents.lNetworkEvents & FD_CONNECT  )
{
    if( T->OnConnect )
        T->OnConnect(T);

    T->lpfn_WSAResetEvent(T->RxOverlapped.hEvent);
}
else if( ( NetEvents.lNetworkEvents & FD_READ) )
{
    rc = T->lpfn_WSARecv(T->CSocket, &T->RxDataBuf, 1, &T->RxBytes, &T->Flags, &T->RxOverlapped, NULL);
    EIndex = T->lpfn_WSAGetLastError();

    if( (rc == SOCKET_ERROR) && (EIndex != WSA_IO_PENDING || EIndex != WSAEWOULDBLOCK ) )
    {
        T->LastErrorCode = EIndex;
        T->SetErrorMsg();
    }
    else
    {
        rc = T->lpfn_WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(1, &T->RxOverlapped.hEvent, true, INFINITE, true);

        if(rc == WSA_WAIT_FAILED)
        {
            T->LastErrorCode = T->lpfn_WSAGetLastError();
            T->SetErrorMsg();
        }
        else
        {
            rc = T->lpfn_WSAGetOverlappedResult(T->CSocket, &T->RxOverlapped, &T->RxBytes, false, &T->Flags);
            if(!rc)
            {
                T->LastErrorCode = T->lpfn_WSAGetLastError();
                T->SetErrorMsg();
            }
            else
            {
                if( T->RxBytes > 0 && T->OnReceive )
                    T->OnReceive(T);

                T->lpfn_WSAResetEvent(T->RxOverlapped.hEvent);
            }
        }
    }
}

return(rc);
}
```

** UPDATE **
I'm finding that the call to 
EIndex = T->lpfn_WSAWaitForMultipleEvents( 1, &T->RxOverlapped.hEvent, false, 3000, true );
inside the Thread function is returning WSA_WAIT_FAILED

And if I disable the thread function and check the return value of 
lpfn_WSAWaitForMultipleEvents, outside the thread, right after the connect call, I get a valid return value of WSAEWOULDBLOCK.

Thinking I might have a problem taking the address-of from inside the thread, I changed the thread code to read as follows:

```
DWORD WINAPI ProcessEvents(void *pParam)
{
 ...

WSAEVENT events[1];

T = (TRANSPORT *)pParam;
Failure = false;


do
{
    events[0] = T->RxOverlapped.hEvent;
    EIndex = T->lpfn_WSAWaitForMultipleEvents( 1, events, false, 3000, true );

            ....
```

and I still cannot manage to make WSAWaitForMultipleEvents happy!

any thoughts/suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If connect() fails, you are calling `SocketShutdown()`.  Presumably, it closes the socket (you did not show that code), but does it terminate the thread first if it is running?  Otherwise, you could be closing the socket behind the thread's back.

Comment: nice catch Remy!  But I believe the connect is succeeding as I have other code I'm using to debug this with where that call works in normal blocking call.  BTW:  Nice to see you around, I use to chat with you on the old Borland news groups! ;)

Comment: additionally, the Establish method call returns TRUE as well.  I removed the call to SocketShutdown() and that didn't resolve.

Comment: The newsgroups still exist, and I am still actively involved with them.  As for the error, do you call WSACloseEvent() anywhere?  Have you tried placing breakpoints everywhere you call WSACloseEvent() and closesocket(), and then see if any of those breakpoints are hit before WSAWaitForMultipleEvents() is called (or while it is busy)?

Comment: Not calling WSACloseEvent anywhere before the call to WSAWaitForMultipleEvents.  I've singled stepped the program and the arguments passed to WSAWaitForMultipleEvents are all valid or as expected yet it keeps throwing an Access Violation.

Comment: correction:  WSAWaitForMultipleEvents is not throwing a fault but rather it consistently returns a -1.  The fault I was experiencing was a race condition between the calling function and the code above both trying to update a debug window.  In any case, I'm still stuck on why WSAWaitForMultipleEvents returns -1.  I'm certain no ther code is calling WSACloseEvent before this point is reached.

Comment: What exactly does WSAGetLastError() return when WSAWaitForMultipleEvents() fails?

Comment: It returns a 5.  Which is so strange as 5 is not one of the return values documented in MSDN.  I've since taken the thread code and move it into the body right after the call to connect and I my fault throwing has come back.
see this thread which is basically a continuation/rework of the above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111528/  Ultimately, I want this to be handled by a thread for the obvious reasons.

Comment: 5 is not a valid winsock error code.  That is an OS error code (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED).  Are you calling WSAGetLastError() IMMEDIATELY after WSAWaitForMultipleEvents() returns -1?  If not, then the socket error code is likely being overwritten before you are retreiving it.  ALWAYS call WSA/GetLastError() IMMEDIATELY after an API function fails, if you are not already doing so.

Comment: Thanks for your help Remy... I found that my pointer to WSAWaitForMultipleEvents was not getting set to the internal winsock.dll function of the same.  cut-n-paste error that I somehow kept over looking the obvious.  sigh...